# How to handle collision after detecting it

Tags: java, collision, rectangles, 2d-games

I've been trying for the past few days to put simple collision into my simple game.  I've looked in lots of places all over the internet but I just haven't found anything to be helpful. I'm just using bounding boxes and all i want the player box to do is stop when it hits the block from any of the four sides (and not get stuck or bounce against the block). Doesn't sound so difficult but I've found it incredibly difficult.  I really just wanna know the code that i need to put in the if statement's brackets, I've read and heard all the theory I can take. Please help if you can.

```
if(bb_collide(player,block)){  //detection works just fine, 
                                      //just not sure what to do afterwards


    }
    else{
        player.setX((player.getX() + velx));
        player.setY((player.getY() - vely));
        player.set_coll(player.getX(),player.getY(),player.getWidth(),player.getHeight());
        block.set_coll(block.getX(),block.getY(),block.getWidth(),block.getHeight());

    }
```

I actually figured it out, I was just having a couple of bad days, sorry if I had like a bad attitude or something but i got it to do what i wanted it to.  Heres what I did if anyone's interested because it works very well for one moving object (mover) bumping into another stationary object (sitter).  It finds the distance between the sides that will collide and sets the velocity to that distance minus a few so it doesnt overlap.  I had the bounding boxes rendering so i could see they overlapped.  Thanks for your replies!

```
    public void Fix_Vel(Player mover, Terrain sitter){

    if(sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getHeight() + mover.getVelX(), mover.getY()) || 
            sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getHeight() + mover.getVelX(), mover.getY() + mover.getHeight()) ){        //mover top right and bottom right coords right collision testing

        mover.setVelX(sitter.getX() - (mover.getX() + mover.getWidth()) - 2);

    }

    if(sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getVelX(), mover.getY()) || 
            sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getVelX(), mover.getY() + mover.getHeight()) ){                               //mover top left + bottom left coords left collision testing

        mover.setVelX((sitter.getX() + sitter.getWidth()) - mover.getX() + 2);  

    }

    if(sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX(), mover.getY() + mover.getVelY()) || 
            sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getWidth(), mover.getY() + mover.getVelY())){                                 //mover top left + top right coords top collision testing

        mover.setVelY((sitter.getY() + sitter.getHeight()) - mover.getY() + 2);


    }

    if(sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX(), mover.getY() + mover.getHeight() + mover.getVelY()) ||                                //mover bottom left and bottom right coords bottom collision testing
            sitter.coll_box.contains(mover.getX() + mover.getWidth(), mover.getY() + mover.getHeight() + mover.getVelY())){

        mover.setVelY(sitter.getY() - (mover.getY() + mover.getHeight()) - 2);
        jumping = false;

        if(mover.getVelY() < 0)
            mover.setVelY(0);   

    }
}
```

Comment: So you want an item to stick to the collided element?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how each box is controlled, so I'm not sure exactly what you want.  If detection works, simply don't allow an object to move if it will cause a collision.

PS: `I really just wanna know the code that i need to put in the if statement's brackets, I've read and heard all the theory I can take.`  To be honest, with that attitude, you're not going to get very far and you're always going to need people's help.  Game programming requires a decent amount of mathematical intuition.  Trigonometry, calculus and linear algebra are essential.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
if(bb_collide(player,block)){
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
}
else{
    player.setX((player.getX() + velx));
    player.setY((player.getY() - vely));
    player.set_coll(player.getX(),player.getY(),player.getWidth(),player.getHeight());
    block.set_coll(block.getX(),block.getY(),block.getWidth(),block.getHeight());

}
```